# extract only unique data from specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that contained roster of employees.Data such as their shifts example is 0700_1500 and their OFf days.
The roster is exported to excel from oracle.At the end of each column i want to know the unique data(what shifts are their in specific column excluding OFf days.

Below is extract of my code.I want to add one line that ignore cell that contains OFf days and arrange in ascending order to display.

```
Dim lastrow As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim rng, lastcell As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)



lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Address & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count).Address), _
    Unique:=True


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unique Sort With Exceptions (Dictionary)

- My setup including the result (in white at the bottom) for the select range `A2:J2`.

[image]

- Adjust the values in the constants section as needed.

**The Code**

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Remarks:      All current filters in the worksheet will be turned off.
'               Error and empty values are excluded.
'               Errors occurring if the columns are greater than the number
'               of columns in the Source Range are only handled by the basic
'               error handler (clearError).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub createUniqueList()
    
' Error
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "createUniqueList"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.

' Constants

    Const uniColumn As Long = 1 ' This is also the 'last row column'.
    Const excColumn As Long = 1
    Const srtColumn As Long = 1
    Const EmptyRows As Long = 0 ' Between the source and the result.
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("OFF", "LEAVE", "CTC") ' add more...

' Let user select First Data Row Range.
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select First Data Row", _
                                   Title:="Obtain Range Object", _
                                   Type:=8)
    If Err.Number = 424 Then
        GoTo UserCanceled
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        GoTo clearError ' Unexpected.
    End If
    On Error GoTo clearError
    ' If you're interested in where an error is occurring after this line,
    ' uncomment the following line.
    'On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Define Source Range.
    
    ' Remove all filters.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    If ws.FilterMode Then
        ws.ShowAllData
    End If
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Define First Data Row Range (remove possible areas and rows).
    Set rng = rng.Areas(1).Rows(1)
    
    ' Define First Cell in Unique Column.
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = rng.Cells(uniColumn)
    ' Define Unique Processing Range.
    Dim pRng As Range
    Set pRng = cel.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - cel.Row + 1)
    ' Define Last Cell in Unique Column.
    Set cel = pRng.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If cel Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit ' No data in Unique Processing Range.
    End If
    ' Define Source Range.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(cel.Row - rng.Row + 1)
    
' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
     
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count < 1 Or rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
' Modify values in Data Array to get unique values.
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long
    ColumnsCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim uniCurrent As Variant
    Dim excCurrent As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    If UBound(Exceptions) >= LBound(Exceptions) Then
    ' There are exceptions.
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            uniCurrent = Data(i, uniColumn)
            If Not IsError(uniCurrent) And Not IsEmpty(uniCurrent) Then
                excCurrent = Data(i, excColumn)
                If IsError(Application.Match(excCurrent, Exceptions, 0)) Then
                    If Not dict.Exists(uniCurrent) Then
                        dict(uniCurrent) = Empty
                        k = k + 1
                        For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
                            Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                        Next j
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Else
    ' There are no exceptions: 'Exceptions = Array()'.
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            uniCurrent = Data(i, uniColumn)
            If Not IsError(uniCurrent) And Not IsEmpty(uniCurrent) Then
                If Not dict.Exists(uniCurrent) Then
                    dict(uniCurrent) = Empty
                    k = k + 1
                    For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
                        Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                    Next j
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

' Write unique values from Data Array to Target Range.
     
    ' Define Target First Cell Range.
    Set cel = rng.Cells(1).Offset(rng.Rows.Count + EmptyRows)
    Set rng = cel.Resize(k, ColumnsCount)
    rng.Value = Data
    
' Sort Target Range.
    
    rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1, srtColumn), _
             Order1:=xlAscending, _
             Header:=xlNo
    
' Confirm success.
    
    Success = True
    GoTo ProcSuccess

ProcExit:
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not transferred.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

ProcSuccess:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Success."
    GoTo ProcExit

ProcFail:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Fail."
    GoTo ProcExit

UserCanceled:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': User canceled."
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcFail

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic 2008.. Plse find link of the excel sheet  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CYGS9ZgsulG8J_qzYEUXWFiXkBHneibv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello VBasic 2008, Thx for your answer.But I have an issue with it.Range(C) it worked perfectly.But the issue is as from Range(D:1)-not all unique data is displayed.For example,In column D-0830_1615 is displayed with OFF but in the exception of not to display there is OFF and also it misses 0600_1400(cell D14).Plse have a look in the excel sheet that I'm sharing with u from my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CYGS9ZgsulG8J_qzYEUXWFiXkBHneibv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code does what it's supposed to. You obviously need something else. Now you have the sample data: instead of my results, manually (type them in) add the desired results. Then supply a link and I'll take a look.